# D Development Process

Tags: module, d, package, libraries, dmd

What is the recommended development process for D programs that use packages that are cloned from github and separately built?

Typically in relation to how C/C++ projects are built using make, autotools, cmake, etc.

Most other build specifications have an install target. Should there be an install target in the build or should we just link a library directly from where it is placed when built and add register its includes in `D_INCLUDE_PATH` and then direct to them using `DFLAGS=-I<D_INCLUDE_PATH>`?

Comment: +1 for the question. Some time ago I was looking for this too and couldn't find anything. Ended up using CMake for my own projects and manually installing libraries to personal root like `~/droot` (so the libraries were in `~/droot/lib`) and specifying this path in CMake configuration. This is far from comfortability of e.g. Java with its Maven or Go with its `go get`.

Comment: Has anyone tried Shake with D?  http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/shake/

Answer (score 2):

I realise my comment can actually be an answer to the question, so here it is:

D development process can't be different than similar in C or C++ world. Is that really difficult to see? Almost all C and C++ compilers generate "native" code. D is not an exception. There was the D.NET project that could target .NET, but it is inactive for years...

Furthermore, all tools used in C/C++ based projects can be easily used for anything else. CMake can be used in Java or .NET projects as well. Same goes for Make and/or Autotools. Why are Maven and Ant more popular in Java world is a different story.

Speaking about them, you can use Maven or Ant in the D development process! Hands down, you need to write your own Maven plugins to make it more easy and flexible, but it is doable, and would in fact be a very nice project.

From what I have seen, D programmers stick to the good, old Make, or write BASH script to do the whole thing. However, I've seen people from the [Lycus](http://www.lycus.org) foundation use [WAF](http://code.google.com/p/waf/). If you are Python programmer, you will just LOVE WAF. If not, try similar things - I've seen people use SCons, Remake, Premake, etc...

[DSSS+Rebuild](http://www.dsource.org/projects/dsss) is the closest thing to a very useful such tool made with D. Unfortunately they are dead projects. :(

I am working on a maven-style tool, but considering the amount of time I have - it will be usable in 2014. :)

Comment: Actually, D building process is very different from C\C++. C\C++ uses header files, and you only need to recompile an implementation file if it is changed, if one of the header files it `include`s changed, if one of the header files `include`d in `header`s file included by that file and so on. If you make a change in an implementation file, you only need to recompile that file. D is different - API and implementation are in the same file, and D heavily relies on template metaprogramming so if you change something you have to recompile everything. This makes incremental builds impossible.

Comment: @IdanArye: Good comment. This is the main reason for me asking. Traditional build tools are a lot about manually specifying dependencies. This is not always true for the D build process. For example when using DMD you can generate D interface files (.di) to speed things up but you don't to have to.

Comment: I agree with Idan, but I did not want to go into such details. After all the question was not about those, but about the overall lifecycle if I am not mistaken. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would go with scons, which has support for D, thanks to Russel Winder:

http://scons.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1268&dsMessageId=2959039

If not, then POM (plain old make).